# Form of matrix satisfying following equations

Tags: matrices, linear-programming

In my lecture notes it states, with no explanation, any 2 × 2 matrix A given by
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_{11} & x_{21}\\
        x_{12} & x_{22}\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

satisfying the two matrix equations

A*(1,1)$^T$=(8,3)$^T$ and (1,1)*A=(2,9)

must take the form

\begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda & 8-\lambda\\
        2-\lambda & 1+\lambda\\
        \end{pmatrix}

Why is this the case? I have solved the two equations to find A is given by
\begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 6\\
        0 & 3\\
        \end{pmatrix} 
but is the matrix with the $\lambda$ coefficients derived?

Comment: I'd like to point out that it is usual to put the suffices the other way around, but I have just copied how you did it.

Comment: What is $\lambda$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From those equations you get $$\begin{align} & x_{11}+x_{21}=8\\&x_{12}+x_{22}=3\\&x_{11}+x_{12}=2\\&x_{21}+x_{22}=9 \end{align}$$
Let $x_{11}=\lambda$. 
$$\begin{align}&\implies x_{21}=8-\lambda\\&\implies x_{12}=2-\lambda\\&\implies x_{22}=9-(8-\lambda)=1+\lambda \end{align}$$
As required.

Answer (score 0):

The equations one obtains should be
$$ x_{11}+x_{21} = 8, \qquad x_{12}+x_{22}=3 \\
x_{11}+x_{12} = 2, \qquad x_{21}+x_{22} = 9 $$
However, these equations will not be independent, because adding the two in each row gives the same equation, $ x_{11}+x_{21} + x_{21}+x_{22} = 11 $. Hence there are actually at most three equations of information here. It turns out that there actually are three, and not less.

Suppose we include one more equation to make the system uniquely invertible: we may specify that $x_{11}=\lambda$ for some $\lambda$. With this, we may solve the rest of the equations to obtain the other entries, which come out as your lecture notes state.